# Django Forms vs Templates

Tags: python, django, forms, templates

Sorry the inconvenient, but I am extremely newbie on Django. I imagined that Django would create the forms for me if I use forms.py, I would not need to create an input tag on template, so I created a test template only, since I created the forms.py. However, running my code I was told that my view didn't return an HttpResponse object, and I suspect it was due to my template having only text on it. Could you help me creating a template to have my forms working ? We can use the example posted above. I will paste it bellow:

```
def create_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreatePostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            my_model = form.save()
            return redirect('/posts/')
        else:
            form = CreatePostForm()
        c = {'form' : form}
        return render(request,'create_post.html',c)
```

Comment: Your example code isn't indented properly, there is a typo in `templtate.html` and you are not parsing the template. Read the Django docs before you ask questions.

Comment: Can you put the print statements before the end of each "if" "else" statements? I think your form validation is failing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return `render()` instead of `HttpResponse`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def create_a_my_model(request):
    ...
    return render(request, 'template.html', c)
```

`template.html` can be very primitive:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button>Save</button>
</form>
```

Also note that the good practice is to redirect to some page after the post request.  This will prevent the double submit.  So the whole code of your view will be:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render

def create_a_my_model(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            my_model = form.save()
            return redirect(my_model) # if the model has `get_absolute_url()`
    else:        
        form = MyModelForm()
    return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': form})
```

If you model doesn't have the `get_absolute_url()` method the you can redirect to any other url: `return redirect('/success/page/')`

Comment: I really appreciate your help, however I still have the same error.
This is what I have as error:
Exception Value: 
The view blogapp.views.create_post didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: I replaced the HttpResponse by :
return render(request,'create_post.html',c)

Comment: Edit your question and copy-n-paste the code of the `create_post()` view.  There can be the indentation problems, so I need to look at the exact code you run.

Comment: I guessed right - here is the wrong indentation.  The `else` part and code below should be moved to one level left. Compare your code and mine. Your version returns nothing then the `request.method == 'GET'`.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, I know that it must be terrible to give attention to those very basic questions and stupid errors, but I really appreciate your attention to my question. Fixed